# How to know if rows are deleted using mysqli dbdriver

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, delete-row

I am using codeigniter 2.1.0 with mysqli dbdriver.
I have the below query and would like to know when it is successful

```
$query = $this->db->query("delete FROM abc WHERE id IN (" . $IdList . ")");
```

How can I know if the related rows are deleted?

Comment: Be very careful that `$IdList` has been escaped; you might want to read up on [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: HI eggyal The issue is that how do I know if the row has been actually deleted, I had tried you option in one place and the query had run but I don't know what issue was there, but  the row was not deleted from mysql

Answer (score 2):

`$this->db->affected_rows()` is what you are looking for. You should be able to compare that result with the expected number of deleted rows.

Also quoting the [USER GUIDE](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html)

> Displays the number of affected rows, when doing "write" type queries (insert, update, etc.).
>
> Note: In MySQL "DELETE FROM TABLE" returns 0 affected rows. The
>   database class has a small hack that allows it to return the correct
>   number of affected rows. By default this hack is enabled but it can be
>   turned off in the database driver file.

Answer (score 1):

From the [CodeIgniter User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html):

> The **`query()`** function returns a database result **object** when "read" type queries are run, which you can use to [show your results](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html). When "write" type queries are run it simply returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on success or failure.

Therefore your `$query` variable will be `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure.